# EF 6.1 connection/execution retry

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835) states that the DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy `will wrap any exceptions that could be transient to inform users that they might want to enable connection resiliency`. My question is: Where do i check for it? Should I catch a "TransientEFException" or check a property or maybe something else?

Comment: I think the idea is that you once you get this exception indicating you might want to enable connection resiliency, you switch to a different execution strategy - say a DbExecutionStrategy.

Comment: @Eric what if it's not a transient problem?!? what if my DB crashed for good or maybe theres a bug in my query?!?

Comment: You have some control over the retry logic, including deciding which exceptions are retried (via ShouldRetryOn) and also the retry strategy (e.g. fixed or exponential, number of retries, etc.).